# a noun just before the relative clause referring the whole sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

Consider:

> They may play games, sports or simply sit and chat together, activities which are far healthier than sitting alone hunched over a screen.

Can we omit *activities*?

> They may play games, sports or simply sit and chat together, which are far healthier than sitting alone hunched over a screen.

Also is it appropriate to place a noun (*activities*) just before  the relative clause referring the whole sentence? In many cases, these are typically the same structure.

Comment: You need an *or* here: *They may play games **or** sports or simply sit and chat together...*

Comment: Using "activities" makes it clear what "which" applies to: all the options rather than just the last.

Comment: Why would you want to omit activities>

Comment: any of which are far healthier...

Comment: Your original example, "They may play games, sports or simply sit and chat together, activities which are far healthier than sitting alone hunched over a [computer?] screen" sounds just right to me. Omitting "activities" makes it less clear in my opinion. Have you taken the "Tour" yet? To find it, just click on the question mark in a circle at the top of this page. Welcome to EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

As I see this question, it all depends on how the author wants to treat the antecedent. If he/she chooses to consider it as a set of activities, then he/she can do away with "activities", but then has to change the number of the verb.

- They may play games, sports or simply sit and chat together, which **is** far healthier than sitting alone hunched over a screen.

On the other hand, if the antecedent is to be treated as separate activities, "activities" is necessary (and the number of the verb remains unchanged, of course).

- They may play games, sports or simply sit and chat together, activities which are far healthier than sitting alone hunched over a screen.

The reason for that would be that the identification of the antecedent is not made easily in this case; there is a missing point of view: you could substitute "pastime" for activities, and the sentence would make sense too, but you'd be looking at the things mentioned under a somewhat different light. you could even speak of time-killing activities, instead. You might then say "But why should one choose among the possible points of view available?", and there is nothing I can answer, particularly so, in the light of the possibility of treating the antecedent as a set; nevertheless, using a "rounding-up term" seems rather necessary to me.

Comment: what do you mean by "the number of the verb". I couldn't understand the explanation for your first example. Could you clarify it ?

Comment: @aquestion https://www.toppr.com/ask/content/concept/the-verb-persons-and-numbers-205317/